# mysql check booking overlap time between two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, overlap

I Have a table booking which has two columns job_time_beg and job_time_end and jobs starts from 8:00 and goes till 16:00 Now I need to if the available time overlap with the given time so that I know I dont want to book within this given time.

I am using

```
      select count(*)as cnt from orders
      where job_date = '2021-02-04'
      and job_truck  = '24'
      and ((job_time_beg >= '10:00' and job_time_beg < '12:00')
           or (job_time_end > '(11):00' and job_time_end <= '12:00'))
        AND order_status_id in (1,5)
```

this works fine for most cases but if there is a booking between 8:00 and 11:00 this query does not work and shows that the time 10:00 to 12:00 is available which overlap between 8:00 and 11:00
I also tried

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt
FROM orders
 WHERE
 job_date = '$data'
      and job_truck  = '$truck' and
(
   '$start' BETWEEN job_time_beg and job_time_end 
   OR
   '$end' BETWEEN job_time_beg and job_time_end
)
        AND order_status_id in (1,5)
```

which works for the 8:00 and 11:00 overlap but does not work when the booking is available for ex start time can be equal to end time in the next booking if we have booking 8:00 to 10:00 and we get time 10:00 to 12:00 this does not overlap because we can assign next booking from 10:00.

Please have a look at sql fiddle
[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0b380/1)

Comment: What is the data type of `job_time_beg` and `job_time_end`?

Comment: No `FROM` clause?

Comment: @Popeye data type is time

Comment: @jarlh FROM orders as I mentioned in the second query

Comment: Use  explicit `<.. and .. <` instead of `BETWEEN` to exclude interval boundaries.

Comment: The test for overlaps is as follows: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts.

Comment: And see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic for overlap for two time periods is:

- The first begins before the second ends.
- The first ends after the second begins.

In your query, the logic would be:

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt
FROM orders
WHERE job_date = @job_date AND
      job_truck  = @truck AND
      @start < job_time_end AND
      @end > job_time_begin AND
      order_status_id IN (1, 5);
```

Note the use of named parameters.  **Don't munge query strings with parameter values!**. Parameters prevent unexpected and hard-to-debug syntax errors.  They also protect the code from SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score -1):

How about this? Not tested, Please check on your DB.

```
and ( (job_time_beg between '10:00' and '12:00')
      or ('10:00' between job_time_beg and job_time_end) )
```

You can convert between to `<` and `>` as per your requirement on edge time.